# Extending Claims Application - Cannot View Afterwards

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, search, central-administration, web-application

I am trying to extend a claims based application (which uses a custom token provider) to enable SharePoint Search on SharePoint Foundation 2010. After I extend the application to use windows login I get a 404 error on the page.This is even after setting up the new extended "site" in the alternate access mapping as a Custom zone. I am at a loss because I can't setup my crawl through the Search Service Application without being able to access the zone which contains windows authentication.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you using the Claims based authentication with FBA or something else?
i think if you just enable both authentication method under the "Claim Authentication Types" Windows and Form based  then you dont need to extend it.

- Central Admin > Security > Under General Security  click .."Specify
  Authentication Providers"
- from this page, select the web app you want from top right.
- on this click on "default" Zone
- on this page Under the "**Claim Authentication Types**" check both
  options "**Enable Windows Authentication**" and "**Enable Forms Based
  Authentication (FBA)**"

Run a crawl now, make sure Content Access account having the right permission on web app level.